# Go to implementation in c# class leads to decompiled class instead of the original class file in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.4.4

I have one .Net core project solution.
In one of the classes where I have declared an object for a class reference, when I try to "Go to Implementation" (Ctrl + F12) it leads to the decompiled class file which is not editable.

Expected: It should lead to the original class file.

I tried the same in other systems and it is working fine due to which it narrows down our issue to system specific for VS 2022.

I have also ensured that the proper using directive is provided to the class from where I am trying to access the "Go to implementation" for other class.

I also tried restarting my Visual studio 2022

Please provide any support to fix the issue.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here? Are you going to the implementation of the class within a specific namespace that is causing this issue? Please let me know the steps to reproduce this issue. Do you have problems with the VS 2022 version under win11? Will there be problems trying to implement other classes?

Comment: `deleting the reference to the project file that includes that class, and then adding it back to my references again.` Does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue around the same time you did. What fixed it for me was deleting the reference to the project file that includes that class, and then adding it back to my references again.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the hidden ".vs" folder in the solution folder did it for me.